# Manipulating data for propensity score matching following multiple imputation with mice package

Tags: r, multiple-imputation, propensity-scores, matching, mice

I've completed multiple imputation of my dataset for the first time using the `mice` package in R. I'm familiar with the procedure for using the `MatchIt` package for propensity score matching using a normal dataframe. However, I'm not at all familiar with how to manipulate the `mids` object which `mice` outputs after imputation. I looked over a [couple](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221327/multiple-imputation-and-propensity-scores) [relevant](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35955/propensity-score-matching-after-multiple-imputation) threads but the questions being answered are more broad scope (I suppose my questions is more just about the code and functions used).

I don't know that `MatchIt` or `Matching` are capable of making use of the `mids` object, and I'm not sure how to bridge the divide. I could use `with.mids()` to fit a model for the propensity score, but I'm uncertain how I would calculate the actual propensity scores using the `mira` object and move on from there. Alternatively, I could output a long form dataframe with the imputed data sets stacked onto one another using `complete(imp, "long")`, calculate propensity scores for each, average them, and complete matching. However, my outcome variable is imputed, so it's not clear that would be beneficial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second method, using `complete(imp, "long")` is what you need to do. You've probably read the Mitra & Reiter paper distinguishing between the "Within" and "Across" methods, since you mentioned wanting to average propensity scores. With imputed outcome data, you need to use the "Within" approach, and then combine and adjust your estimates using Rubin's rules. So, for each imputed data set, you will do the following: run `matchit()`, and then run your outcome regression model on the matched data set. Once you have done this for each imputed data set, you will recombine the model fits using `as.mira()` and then summarize your `mira` output. Here is some sample code:

```
imp.data <- complete(imp, "long")
fit.list <- setNames(vector("list", length(unique(imp.data$.imp))),
                     unique(imp.data$.imp))
for (i in unique(imp.data2$.imp)) {
  m.out <- matchit(t ~ v1 + v2 + v3, data = imp.data[imp.data$.imp == i,])
  fit.list[[i]] <- glm(y ~ t, data = match.data(m.out))
}
fit.list.mira <- as.mira(fit.list) #combines into mira object for pool()
summary(pool(fit.list.mira))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! I actually haven't read the Mitra & Reiter paper, but I'll take a look at it today and give this a shot.

Comment: It worked beautifully after I adjusted the number of covariates I was including, given there were probably far too many. Thanks again!