# Propensity Score Matching implementation after multiple imputation

Tags: r, spss, propensity-scores, matching

There is a very good thread about Propensity Score Matching after multiple imputation with the articles referred:

> [Propensity score matching after multiple imputation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35955/propensity-score-matching-after-multiple-imputation)

In the refered articles, they talk about

- averaging of propensity scores after multiple imputation, followed by causal inference (method 2 in your post above)
- causal inference using each set of propensity scores from the multiple imputations followed by averaging of the causal estimates.

Method 2 is propensity score matching, lets say when someone imputes 5 datasets, in all 5 of them. **However**, we then end up with 5 propensity score matched cohorts and we want to make 1 propensity matched cohort of it; also how to implement this in SPSS/R, this stays unclear.

Some Articles also talk about the Rubin's Rule for pooling; but could not find good implentation in SPSS/R literature on that, if somebody could help on that I would appreciate it.

**So in short, the question is:** how to properly perform propensity score matching after multiple imputation and how to implement it in SPSS/R?
If anybody has reference material, I would like to read it!

Answer (score 6):

**Update 1/4/20**: A new package has been written for this purpose called `MatchThem`. It's on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=MatchThem), and an article about how to use it is under review. It's compatible with version 4.0.0 of `cobalt` for balance checking. It has built-in functions for performing matching and estimating treatment effects from multiply imputed data. It has integration with `svyglm()` and `svycoxph()`, so you can estimate treatment effects for various forms of outcome. It really smooths out the process of estimating effects from multiply imputed data.

---

I answered [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/257789/manipulating-data-for-propensity-score-matching-following-multiple-imputation-wi/257808#257808) which provides R code for your case after using `mice` to multiply impute, `MatchIt` to match within each imputed data set, and `glm()` to estimate treatment effects in each imputed data set.

See the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cobalt/vignettes/cobalt_A2_cluster_imp.html) for `cobalt` for an example of the other method (averaging propensity scores across imputations).

Comment: thank you very much! The link was very useful! Cobalt documentation was also very useful.

However, when matching the data with 

  `m.out <- matchit(t ~ v1 + v2 + v3, data = imp.data[imp.data$.imp == i,])`, we get matched data per imputed dataset. However, how do we see each matched dataset; how can we take each matched dataset from the total imputed dataset apart; and perform lets say a cox regression per matched dataset per imputed dataset?